# No mapping exists from object type System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, winforms

When I press the register button, a MessageBox will show up and then this happens:

> No mapping exists from object type System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker to a known managed provider native type.

How do I fix this?

```
SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(); 
sqlcon.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=MYCOMPUTER-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Database=COMPPROG;User 
Id=user;Password=password";
SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT (*) as cnt from USERACCOUNT", sqlcon);
SqlCommand cmd = sqlcon.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO USERACCOUNT 
(FName,MName,Sname,TxtBirth,comboGender,textBox8,textBox1,textBox2) 
VALUES(@FName,@MName,@Sname,@TxtBirth,@comboGender,@textBox8,@textBox1,@textBox2)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", FName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MName", MName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sname", Sname.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TxtBirth", TxtBirth);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@textBox8", textBox8.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@textBox1", textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@textBox2", textBox2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comboGender", comboGender);

sqlcon.Open();
MessageBox.Show("Record added sucessfully!", "Registration Success!");
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlcon.Close();
```

Comment: I'm guessing the error happens on the `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TxtBirth", TxtBirth);` line? You need to get the value of the DateTimePicker, not the picker itself.

Comment: It means ".NET doesn't know how to convert a WinForms control into a database field." - You should pass a DateTime object instead (presumably a property of TxtBirth).

Answer (score 1):

Like **@gunr2171** said in comments problem is from this line so change it like this :

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TxtBirth", TxtBirth.Value);
```

This is value of TxtBirth for your query.

**Edit :**

- And your error means you are passing the `DatePicker` itself and it can not be done.